# Laravel9 - Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Could do with some help on this one.

My web.php file has the following code:

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('posts');
});

Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug) {
    $post = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../resources/posts/{slug}.html");
    return view('post' , [
        'post' => $post
    ]);
});
```

When I try to run the code - I get the following error:

> file_get_contents(/Users/username/Sites/blog/routes/../resources/posts/{slug}.html): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Any ideas?  For the avoidance of doubt - I have reviewed online issues prior to posting this message and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a single `$`, it should be

```
$post = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../resources/posts/$slug.html");
```

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the response.  I realised that after returning to review the post and updated it as per your suggestion however, I'm still getting the same error - thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same error? isn't it a new one? Are you sure you are not missing a `views` like `__DIR__ . "/../resources/views/posts/$slug.html"`. At least you should have a new error showing what `$slug` is, so it should be `file_get_contents(/Users/username/Sites/blog/routes/../resources/posts/abc-123-slug.html): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` or whatever you have input for `$slug`...

Comment: here's the error:file_get_contents(/Users/username/Sites/blog/routes/../resources/posts/{$slug}.html): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Hey - big thank you - you were right.  I've now managed to resolve this.  Thanks.

Comment: So, what was the issue? How did you solve it? Could you also mar this answer as correct, please?